# How to combine MP3 files one over another in PHP

Tags: php, audio, merge, mp3

I need to put an MP3 file over another one in a specific time slice of whole file.

Is it possible to do this? If so, is there any library or method?

I dont want to put them one after another. Such as;

```
file_put_contents('combined.mp3',
    file_get_contents('file1.mp3') .
    file_get_contents('file2.mp3'));
```

Comment: I don't think that if you split in half a mp3 you get two working track.. and viceversa.

Comment: Can't be done *"in"* PHP. But of course, PHP can invoke `ffmpeg`, which is suitable to merge/slice audio files.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has limited functionality and it will be slow. i recommend using a native library for such purpose. and execute it using `shell_exec()`.

this one may help. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate .
that example uses ffmpeg. but make sure shell calls are secure.